# Add Function to change place of element

Tags: javascript, html

I want if the local time is in europe that the option europe changes place under the heading "Europe"

This is what I came with:

```js
var userCountry = ""; // Store user's country here (e.g., obtained through geolocation)

var europeanCountries = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden"];

if (europeanCountries.includes(userCountry)) {
  var localOption = document.querySelector("#timezone [value=local]");
  var europeOptgroup = document.getElementById("europe-optgroup");
  europeOptgroup.appendChild(localOption);
}
```

```html
<select id="timezone" onkeyup="filterFunction(this,event)" onchange="changeTimezone()">
  <option value="local" selected>Local Time</option>
  <optgroup label="Europe" id="europe-optgroup">
    <option value="GMT">London</option>
    <option value="Europe/Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
    <option value="Europe/Athens">Greece</option>
    <option value="Europe/Moscow">Moscow</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="USA">
    <option value="America/New_York">New York</option>
    <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Las Vegas</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish? Like perhaps show a before and after version?

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @CalPal 
 i want if the user is in europe that the option "Local" is in the <optgroup id="Europe"> and if the user is in another continent it will stay where it originally is.

Comment: If you set the country to e.g. "Germany", the code works fine.

Comment: @mr-polywhirl What do i have to change?

Comment: `var userCountry = "Germany"`

Comment: You are missing the most important part and that is actually getting the user's country. Otherwise your code works just fine

Comment: @Hidde: *"What do i have to change?"* - You'd start with what **the comment in your own code is telling yourself to do**.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `<select>` element to a function that does the shuffling for you.

```js
const EU_COUNTRIES = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden"];

const main = async () => {
  placeLocalTime(document.querySelector('#timezone'));
};

const placeLocalTime = async (selectEl) => {
  const userCountry = await getUserCountry();
  if (EU_COUNTRIES.includes(userCountry)) {
    const localOption = selectEl.querySelector('option[value="local"]'),
      europeOptgroup = selectEl.querySelector('#europe-optgroup');
    europeOptgroup.prepend(localOption);
  }
};

const getUserCountry = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://geolocation-db.com/json/', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return response.country_name;
  } catch (e) {
  
  }
  return 'Germany'; // Default to Germany... in the case of this snippet
};

main(); // Call main
```

```html
<select id="timezone" onkeyup="filterFunction(this,event)" onchange="changeTimezone()">
  <option value="local" selected>Local Time</option>
  <optgroup label="Europe" id="europe-optgroup">
    <option value="GMT">London</option>
    <option value="Europe/Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
    <option value="Europe/Athens">Greece</option>
    <option value="Europe/Moscow">Moscow</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="USA">
    <option value="America/New_York">New York</option>
    <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Las Vegas</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exactly looking for... but if your looking for getting location and setting option is selected.
`var country = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;` is one option. i.e the output could be `America/Toronto` or `Europe/Athens` where you are located it will be different for testing.

Then you could check if that has which you have requested `Europe` then you can set the value of the options based on if it has Europe in it. Or else it will default the option of local time.

Then you can use the select Value property change the option based on where there are located. `var localOption = document.querySelector("#timezone");`

`localOption.value = country;`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

***just of note this will not work unless your are actually in Europe or you Manually set your location. ***

Here is an example of what you might be looking for
https://jsfiddle.net/5nvkby3q/